# Cross database query engine for Oracle database using Qt

Tags: database, oracle, qt, cross-platform

I am developing an Qt application where I want to query data from tables in 2 different databases at once. I am using Oracle as the database but my employer wants me to achieve this without making a database link between the 2 databases. So I thought of developing a cross database query engine using Qt sql module objects. But it should not be as complex as an sql parser. I just want query data from tables in two databases and display them in 1 view and do these queries using a common interface. But according to my knowledge Qt sql modules can be used to query from only 1 database. If there is anyone who has done this kind of programming before or someone who has an idea about this, your suggestions are much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Different Oracle databases?  On separate physical hosts, or separate Oracle instances?  [Oracle's dblink functionality](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/server.101/b10759/statements_5005.htm) is a better idea than a roll-your-own setup.

Comment: Yes, the two databases are in the same physical host, which means I'm talking about 2 instances. The reason why my employer wants me not to use dblink is some users don't have the privileges to see all the tables in those instances, so if I use dblink to query and a user with less privileges use my application, they'll be able to make undesired queries.

Comment: Databases are not instances - an instance can hold multiple databases.  Could be a matter of granting access (based on role I hope) to the other database, no need for dblink but the real issue appears to be grants

Comment: Think of it this way. The users of this application will log in using TNS aliases. So each alias has different privileges. I'm using these aliases to connect to 2 database schemas called ATS and SER. And I want to query tables in both these schemas. What I have done so far is I have created 2 QSqlDatabase objects and connect to each schema using the TNS alias. But in order to make cross database queries, i have to do it manually each time, which is a very hectic task. so I want to develop an common interface (possibly an API) and call some methods to make these queries

Comment: There's no need for two logins, just access in the ATS schema from SER, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like that some time ago by opening multiple database connections using [QSqlDatabase](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqldatabase.html).

Thus, inspired by the official documentation you can try something like this:

```
 //Open database 1:
 QSqlDatabase db1 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI","db1");
 db.setHostName("acidalia");
 db.setDatabaseName("tns1");
 db.setUserName("mojito");
 db.setPassword("J0a1m8");
 bool ok = db.open();

 ..
 //Open database 2:
 QSqlDatabase db2 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI","db1");
 ..
 db.setDatabaseName("tns2");
 ..
```

Now the databasese are open and you can the use them in a query. Take note of the scope of the db variables as per the doc:

```
 {
     QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("db1");
     QSqlQuery query("SELECT NAME, DOB FROM EMPLOYEES", db);
 }

 {
     QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::database("db2");
     QSqlQuery query("SELECT NAME, DOB FROM EMPLOYEES", db);
 }

 //Clean up
 QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("db1"); 
 QSqlDatabase::removeDatabase("db2");
```

See [removeDatabase](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqldatabase.html#removeDatabase) on cleaning up